# HTML Button appearing behind images in Safari

Tags: css, safari

I distributed some images on the z-axis, then used the mouse as a (fake) 3D camera so that perspective changes while you move the mouse cursor and it works perfectly in Chrome but the button shows up behind all the images in Safari browser so you can't see it. I tried using z-index but it did not work.

```
<div class="cd-background-wrapper">
    <figure class="cd-floating-background">
        <img src="img/cd-img-1.jpg" alt="image-1">
        <img src="img/cd-img-2.png" alt="image-2">
        <img src="img/cd-img-3.png" alt="image-3">
    </figure>
<a class="follow fade-in three" id="fade-btn" href="#"><img 
class="follow-btn" src="/static/assets/images/Follow.gif"/></a>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.cd-floating-background {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
 }
.cd-background-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-size: cover;
 position: relative;
} 
.cd-floating-background {
transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

 .cd-floating-background img:first-child {
transform: translateZ(50px);
}

.cd-floating-background img:nth-child(2) {
transform: translateZ(290px);
 }

.cd-floating-background img:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateZ(400px);
 }

.follow::before,
 .follow::after {
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 transition: all 0.5s;
}
 .follow {
 position: absolute;
 top: 93%;
 left: 51%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index to change z-axis position. Set it to any number greater than 1 (1 is default value) and set position property.

```
.follow  {
        z-index: 2;
        position: relative;
 }
```

z index property will help you.